# How can I pass different numbers to a function in Bash script?

Tags: bash

I have a function named myfunction.C which takes a number as input. I want to have a Bash script to iterate through numbers `0` to `99` in my function.
I had this code working before, but now it passes `{0..99}` instead of just one number to myfunction. What is wrong here?

```
for i in {0..99}
do
root -b -q -l myfunction.C++\($i\)
done
exit 0
```

Comment: Run your script using `bash` not `dash`.  In other words, run `bash /path/to/myscript`.

Comment: While legal, you are better served by not putting `'.'` and `'++'` in your function names.

Comment: my function name does not have . or ++ in it. My function's name is myfunction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're actually *using* `bash` to run this script, either by explicitly doing it:

```
bash myScript.sh
```

or by using a shebang line, first line in the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

If, for some reason you don't have `bash` available to you, "lesser" shells can generally call of the external `seq` program to do something similar, something like:

```
for i in $(seq 1 12) ; do echo $i ; done
```